# the --now switch of `systemctl`

Tags: systemd, startup, services, systemctl

As stated in the [man](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html) page,

```
systemctl --now enable servicename
```

should **enable** and **start** the service.

But it never works for me, under many different distributions.

While the output of:

`systemctl is-enabled` turns enabled,

`systemctl is-active` is still inactive for the service.

What this switch is good for?

I've tried other combinations such as:

```
systemctl enable --now servicename
```

and:

```
systemctl enable servicename --now
```

but still the same; I have to manually `systemctl start servicename` every time, even if the previous command (ie the `enable` part) executes *successfully*.

Is it that the application's implentation of systemd service should support it implementing the feature somewhere in the unit files; what many well-known services do not follow, that made me think its entirely useless switch; I assume thinking over it.

Comment: All "combinations" work fine here (archlinux).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've found that annoying as well.

Looks like the `--now` switch was added in version 220 (see [this line](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/dd95b381b26369c02a3ca03585184cb2ea17295b/NEWS#L3043-L3046) in the changelog), and CentOS 7 is currently on version 219. Hopefully soon then!

You can check your version of systemd with `systemctl --version`.

Comment: FYI I am on CentOS 7 and `# systemctl --version` tells me I'm using `systemd 219` but I have verified that the `--now` flag indeed starts a stopped service. Maybe RHEL/CentOS backporting?

Comment: Hi @pzkpfw same for me, even I am on 219 and --now works for me.